# How to reinstall Windows 8 after it has been deleted?

Tags: windows-8, installation, reinstall

I have a laptop on which a Ubuntu 14.04 installation removed my complete Windows 8 installation.

How can I install Windows again? I do not have any CDs or DVDs for Windows.

Comment: Meaning, have you installed Ubuntu 14.04 in the same partition where Windows 8 was installed?

Comment: Where to get the license key from?

Comment: There should be a license sticker on the computer. On some laptops it is under the battery.

Comment: On most Win 8 installs it's no longer licensed like that due to secure boot... The TPM takes care of it if Windows is pre-installed. You either buy the manufacturer restore disks or buy retail Windows. I know which is cheaper. This will also teach you to make the recovery disks when your computer reminds you the first time you use it.

Comment: the product key is stored inside the UEFI and Windows 8 setup detects and uses this key